# Expressing Eisenstein series E_k in terms of E_4 and E_6

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Given an Eisenstein series $E_k$ (of level 1), it is a polynomial $P_k(E_4,E_6)$ in $E_4$ and $E_6$, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series#Recurrence_relation should give a finite algorithm for doing so.

Do we know any properties of these polynomials $P_k$ or are there any formulas? A quick internet search didn't turn up with anything, but maybe I just didn't know what to search.

(As before, if somebody knows enough about the subject to tell me if this is appropriate for overflow, e.g. not found in a common textbook, then I might want to post it there instead.)

Comment: Are the recursive formulas for $P_k$ not enough? Do you want the formula in closed form?

Comment: A closed form is optimal, but I suspect it does not exist or else it would also be on the wikipedia page. I just mean the recursion determines the polynomials P_k, but naively I can only extract information about a finite number of these polynomials at a time (which isn't enough if you want to prove something for all k say). 

But judging by the response, it doesn't seem like that much is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are looking for. But yes, there are some results about the polynomials $P_k$. For instance, Swinnerton-Dyer has proven that if $p>5$ is a prime, then $P_{p-1}$ is $p$-integral, and its reduction mod $p$ has no multiple factors (so, a fortiori, $P_{p-1}$ also has no multiple factors). Also, $P_{p-1}-1$ is irreducible.

Comment: Is it $p>5$ or $p>3$? I probably knew this at some time, but how does the proof that $P_{p-1}-1$ is irreducible work again?

Comment: Dear @Dtseng: I'm afraid you'll have to look in Swinnerton-Dyer's paper. If you can read French, Serre's Bourbaki paper *Congruences et formes modulaires* explains these things very nicely. Regards,